# Не обновляется разметка

Tags: java, android

```
public class game extends Activity {
    ImageButton imageButton5;
    TextView textView3;
    TextView textView4;
    TextView textview5;
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask mTimerTask;
    TimerTask OutputResultats;
    Handler h;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textview5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        imageButton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);
    }
    public void OutputResultats(View view) {
        timer = new Timer();
        imageButton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
        if (timer != null) {
            h.postDelayed(settD, 1000);
        }
    }

    //обновляем разметку в основном потоке
    Runnable settD = (new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            final int pS = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            final int cS = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            textView3.setText("Ваш результат:" + pS);
            textView4.setText("Результат компьютера:" + cS);
            if (pS < cS) {
                textview5.setText("Победил компьютер!Повезёт в следующий раз!");
            } else {
                textview5.setText("Вы выиграли!Поздравляю!");
            }
            if (pS == cS) {
                textview5.setText("Победила дружба;)");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Ругается на строчку,где обновляется разметка,а именно:

```
textView3.setText("Ваш результат:" + pS );
textView4.setText("Результат компьютера:" + cS);
```

Не знаю почему,если есть идеи,то,пожалуйста,напишите мне.Заранее благодарю

Comment: содержимое "ругательства" должно прилагаться

Answer (score 3):

```
setContentView(R.layout.game);
```

должно быть до присваивания вьюх

```
 textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
 textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
 textview5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
 mageButton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
```

То есть вы дергали вьхи по айдишникам из разметки, которая еще не лежит